# How to assign value to NSManaged object in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I need to write test case and in the test case, I need to mock an object of the following class and put them into an array. e.g. `moviesArray = [MovieCoreData]`. I am wondering how I can instantiate this?

```
@objc(MovieCoreData)
class MovieCoreData {

    static var genre: Genre = "Comedy"

    @NSManaged var actor: String
    @NSManaged var released: Bool
    @NSManaged var name: String?

    public static func mapping() -> [FieldName: String] {
        return [
            "actor": "actor",
            "released": "released",
            "name": "name"
        ]
    }
}
```

For example, I tried to write

`moviesArray = [MovieCoreData(actor: "Johnny Depp", released: True, name: "Pirate Captain"]`

and

`moviesArray.first.actor = "Johnny Depp"`

`moviesArray.first.released = "true"`

`moviesArray.first.name = "Pirate Captain"`

none of them worked, I admit I don't know much about `Objective-C` and `NSManaged`, can someone tell me how to create an array of `MovieCoreData` with fake data?

Answer (score 1):

The `@NSManaged` attribute belongs to Core Data.

The class must be a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and instances must be created with regard to the `NSManagedObjectContext` to take advantage of its functionality